# How to reorganize folders into dated folders for picasa

Tags: file-management, picasa

I have photos in `DCIM\g343asdfj` Folders that have been indexed in picasa and facetagged. Now I want to move them to `photos\2013-02-23` or as required by the date taken of the picture. How do I do that in picasa automatically without losing information?

One think I can do is use an external tool to do it and readd it into picasa, but then it will add duplicates to the collection and have to redo the face tagging?

Picasa has an import to dated feature which does this, but then it creates duplicates of the photo (and I have about 20GB to organize). So my question is has anyone done this successfully for their own collection?

Comment: I tried moving some existing files into new directories and picasa was able to find all the tags correctly.

Comment: However, any albums containing the photos, don't have those photos anymore!

Answer (score 1):

Picasa is very limited when renaming files - you can do the following:

1. Embed your faces into metadata by Picasa
2. Rename your files by a third-party tool (photo renaming or photo management tool)
3. Import your files back to Picasa

Or probably even better consider more serious photo management tool for your future image management tasks. Because if you'll need to change your file names in one sunny day you need to look to repeat the above steps again.

Comment: Are there any serious photo management tools that do a great job of auto face tagging?